# Disable wait time before marking item as read

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

One of my directors has recently got a new PC. I've set up Outlook on his new PC as it was on his old one.

One question he has raised is the mark as read feature. He only want's the e-mail to be marked as read when he opens up the e-mail to read it/reply to the email. Otherwise he wants it marked as unread so he could go back onto it later on.

Now the option to do this is relatively easy, and all the Google results point to the option i.e go to reading pane in advanced options and tick Mark items as read..... . However, there's one option you can't disable, which is the "Wait x seconds before marking item as read". I find it quiet odd that you can't disable this outright, you can only increase the time.

However, if there anyway to disable this at all? I could increase the time to 600 seconds or so, which is enough time for him not to notice anything, but just thinking if there's another way? Also I know he could mark them as read with shortcuts, but I don't imagine he would have the patience.

[image: Wait time option]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear two checkboxes in the reading pane options: "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" and "Mark item as read when selection changes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The timer is only in effect when the option above it is checked.  Once you uncheck "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane", it is no longer relevant.

Comment: But once you uncheck it, it will just mark the email as read once you click on another email.

Comment: To stop that you have to uncheck the setting "Mark item as read when selection changes" as well.